# SAP: Creating a timesheet entry with a OData web service

Tags: web-services, odata, sap-gateway, sap-hr

I would like to create a time booking/recording using an OData web service in SAP S/4HANA (release 2021 FP2 SP3).

I have found `HCM_TIMESHEET_MAN_SRV` as an OData web service and can also retrieve the metadata for it. Somehow the EntityType 'TimeEntry' does not have a field to enter hours. Could it be that I am using the wrong service? Or is it even possible to create time entry records with `HCM_TIMESHEET_MAN_SRV`?

Comment: which version of S4HANA system are you using?

Comment: As there are different ODATA services based on S4HANA version

Comment: release 2021 FP2 SP3

Answer (score 0):

From the FIORI reference library, [My Timesheet (Version 2)](https://fioriappslibrary.hana.ondemand.com/sap/fix/externalViewer/#/detail/Apps(%27F1312%27)/S17OP) is linked with the ODATA Service `HCM_TIMESHEET_MAN_SRV` that you are referring to. However the validity seems to end with S4HANA 1909 FP2.

There is newer version of Time sheet FIORI application [My Timesheet (Version 3)](https://fioriappslibrary.hana.ondemand.com/sap/fix/externalViewer/#/detail/Apps(%27F3074%27)/S23OP), that has latest validity and is referring to ODATA service `HCMFAB_TIMESHEET_MAINT_SRV`. Probably you should use this ODATA service to post time sheets (provided that the ODATA service is activated correctly and also HR module customization is maintained correctly).

**Additional Info:** ODATA service of a FIORI app can be found in `Implementation Information` tab, `Configuration` section of the FIORI URL's I have mentioned above. The validity of FIORI applications can be checked there as well.